# JavaScript timers after Hibernate/Sleep or process close

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome, session

I am trying to create a session timer in JavaScript and .NET. That is I record the time on the server on page load add to it the session time from the web.config after when the timer expires I redirect the user to the log in screen (there's a timer showing in between).

Now this works fine an dandy except for two scenarios:
- I sleep/hibernate the PC
- I close the browser (Chrome)

When I reload the browser or switch on the PC, not only does the timer not resume and never log the user out, but the even the debug panel has mysteriously disappeared. See pic.

Anybody know of any limitations on browsers when dealing with intervals?

[image]

The code of the interval look a bit like this:

```
var intervalTimer;
if (userId) {
    intervalTimer = setInterval(function () {
        // Get todays date and time
        var currentTime = new Date();

        if (currentTime > dateLoginExpireTime) {
            //Session Expired
            //code to log out
        }
        else if (currentTime > dateLoginWarningTime) {              
            //Warning Time
            //show warning message                             
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```